# BigQuery table schema for history data

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have some data to store in BigQuery but I don't really know what is the best table schema to do so.

My dataset is composed of Elements, that are themselves composed of SubElements :

```
[
   {
      "elementId":"someID1",
      "field1":"someField",
      "subElements":[
         {
            "subElementId":"someSubID1",
            "field2":"someField"
         },
         {
            "subElementId":"someSubID2",
            "field2":"someField"
         }, ...
      ]
   },
   {
      "elementId":"someID2",
      "field1":"someField",
      "subElements":[
         {
            "subElementId":"someSubID1",
            "field2":"someField"
         },
         {
            "subElementId":"someSubID2",
            "field2":"someField"
         }, ...
      ]
   }, ...
]
```

I receive this Dataset once a day, and I want to store in BigQuery the history of the different configuration (fields values) of my elements.

A possible data schema would be for example :

```
[
   {
      "name":"elementId",
      "type":"STRING",
      "mode":"NULLABLE"
   },
   {
      "name":"states",
      "type":"RECORD",
      "mode":"REPEATED",
      "fields":[
         {
            "name":"stateDatetime",
            "type":"DATETIME",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         },
         {
            "name":"field1",
            "type":"STRING",
            "mode":"NULLABLE"
         },
         {
            "name":"subElements",
            "type":"RECORD",
            "mode":"REPEATED",
            "fields":[
               {
                  "name":"field2",
                  "type":"STRING",
                  "mode":"NULLABLE"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Where I append Element fields to the repeated field `states` if one of the fields (from the Element or any SubElement) is different from the latest stored state.

Is this an efficient way to store my data ? The main queries I will use on this table are for example :

- `field2` value for a given `elementId` and `subElementId` at a given date (if no state at the given date, must retrieve the closest older state)
- latest `field1` value for a given `elementId`